# Equivalence of Definitions of Closed Sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let E be a set. Two definitions of closed sets in literature are:

1. E is closed if E contains the limit of every convergent sequence of points in E. [Ross, 2013]
2. E is closed if E contains every limit point of E. [Rudin, 1976]

The set of *limits of every convergent sequence of points in E*, and the set of *limit points of E*, is not necessarily equal, so are these two definitions equivalent?

Comment: They are equivalent in metric spaces (and in fact in a considerably larger class of spaces), but they are not equivalent in topological spaces in general.

Comment: Both spaces in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1161184/12042) are examples of spaces in which the two definitions are not equivalent: in each case the point of $X$ sent to $1$ is in the closure of the rest of the space but not the limit of any sequence in the rest of the space.

Comment: Interesting - let's consider metric spaces only then. Let $A$ denote the set of limits of every convergent sequence of points in $E$, and let $B$ denote the set of limit points of $E$. As mentioned, $A$ might not be equal to $B$. Because these two definitions are equivalent, then it must mean $A$ \ $B$ $\in E$ (if A is larger) or $B$ \ $A$ $\in E$ (if B is larger), right?

Comment: $A=E\cup B$; this set is the closure of $E$, the smallest closed set containing $E$. Thus, $E$ is closed iff it already contains $B$, in which case of course it also contains $A$.

Comment: Thanks Brian M. Scott. This makes it really clear what the relationship is between $A$, $B$, and $E$. Going off-topic a little - Rudin does not seem to talk about the set $A$ and its connection to limit points - is this something typically covered in more detail in a topology course or text?

Comment: Yes.  Between text proper and exercises, many topology texts will run through a fairly extensive catalogue of basic facts about such matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you used the tag "real analysis" I'm guessing you are working in the reals?  As @Brian M. Scott mentioned your two definitions are equivalent in a metric space, so if you are working in the reals they are equivalent.

Hint to prove it:  if $x$ is a limit point of $E$, consider $(x-1/n,x+1/n)\cap E$.